# Whatever I tried, my computer keeps waking up when I move my mouse

Tags: windows-10, mouse, bluetooth, sleep, dell-precision

My computer is a Dell Precision 5550, connected to a Dell WD19TB Thunderbolt Docking Station.
It runs a Windows 10 OS and my mouse is a Logitech MX Master (Mac) 3 connected through bluetooth.

Whatever I tried to do, which means checking every device in my device manager, and making sure it doesn't wake up from any mouse or keyboard, removing all wake timer and checking BIOS to make sure there isn't anything there that might make it wake up.

Checking "powercfg -devicequery wake_armed" returns NONE.

And still, just moving my mouse a little bit after setting my PC in sleep mode wakes it up. The worst part is that if I bump into my table, it will also wake up.

What can I try next?

*Disclaimer:
I want to still be able to wake up my pc from my keyboard, and shutting off the mouse doesn't really works because it picks up movements when I flip it to switch it off.
I also would rather solve the problem than use a workaround.

Comment: Easy fix: don't move the mouse.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you don't want your computer to wake from a sleep state, by moving your mouse or using your keyboard, how are you going to wake your computer?

Comment: What you see is entirely normal in the numerous computers I have worked on.

Comment: What "wake-up" do you mean? Wake-up from "idle" with screen off but PC running or wake-up from a suspend mode (e.g. suspend-to-RAM or suspend-to-disk)? The device manager settings AFAIK only work for idle mode and suspend-to-RAM. For suspend-to-disk and soft-off state the BIOS settings are important (and to my experience there you often can only enabled/disable mouse+keyboard).

Comment: Low-tech solution: Unplug the mouse.

Comment: Turn off the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your Bluetooth mouse off before putting your computer to sleep.

Thus, only your trackpad and keyboard (both hard to access while accidentally hitting the table) can wake up your computer from its slumber.

Comment: This is what I do now, and exactly what I'm trying to avoid.
If I don't turn off the mouse quickly enough, the PC goes to sleep then wakes up immediately when it picks up my hand on the on off switch.

Comment: Considering that you're using a laptop computer, turn your mouse off **before** putting your computer to sleep.

Comment: I asked for how to prevent my mouse from waking my computer from sleep, not for workarounds.

Comment: This is not really helpful. If you are unable to answer the question please refrain from telling people to "do it properly".

Comment: It works, but it is a rather cumbersome way, since you have to rely on toggling on and off a little switch that was meant for very seldom occasions.